# Fabio-consul load balancer for nginx web-servers

Tags: nginx, consul

My goal is incoming http traffic on consul, forward to web-servers(nginx) using fabio load balancer.

1- I've a cluster where consul is in front-end, expecting fabio to be setup on same server

2-  10-20 web-servers(nginx), registered as consul-client with front-end 
consul server, services and health checks registered well.

The fabio is very new for me, please help me how to configure things...

Answer (score 1):

You got it a bit wrong, Consul is service discovery, traffic dosesn't go through it.

Register the nginx servers in Consul (same service name, different id for each instance). don't forget the required tag for Fabio (urlprefix by default).

Route all your traffic to Fabio, if everything is configured correctly it should workd (Fabio picks up the service tag in consul and knows to which server to route traffic according to the tag set in Consul)